# Entering a 2d array in a frame in C

Tags: c, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to have the user input a 2d array and then it would print out that array in something like a frame, i wrote the code and it works but when it comes to printing the array the program just prints the first row of what the user inputted over and over like this:

```
Enter size
3
Enter Array
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Your Array:
     a b c    
   # # # # # 
1  # 1 2 3 # 
2  # 1 2 3 # 
3  # 1 2 3 # 
   # # # # #
```

Here is my code: I feel its a small error but i just can't find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i,j;
    int y,x;
    int n,a,num,readNum,z;
    char ch;

    ch = 'a';
    num = 1;

    printf("Enter size\n");
    readNum = scanf("%d",&z);

    int Board[z][z];
    n = z+2;
    a = n+1;

    printf("Enter Array\n");
    for(x=0;x<z;x++){
        for(y=0;y<z;y++){
           readNum = scanf("%d",&Board[x][y]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nYour Array:\n");
    x=0;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        y=0;
        for(j=0;j<a;j++){
            if(((i==0)&&(j==1))||
               ((i==1)&&(j==0))||
               ((i==0)&&(j==n))||
               ((j==0)&&(i==n))){
                printf("   ");
            }
            if ((i==0)&&(j==0)){
                printf("  ");
            }
            if ((i==0 && (j>=2 && j<n))){
                printf("%c ",ch);
                ch++;
            }
            if ((j==0) &&(i>=2 && i<n)){
                printf("%d  ",num);
                num++;
            }
            if(((i==1) && (j>=1 && j<=n))||
               ((i==n) && (j>=1 && j<=n))||
               ((j==1) && (i>1  && i<n ))||
               ((j==n) && (i>1  && i<n ))){
                printf("# ");
            }
            if((i>1 && i<n) && (j>1 && j<n)){ 
                printf("%d ",Board[x][y]);
                y++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks as though you're not updating `x`.

Comment: What's wrong with `print row of stars; [print star, print row 0, print star, linefeed; repeat n rows;] print row of stars;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `x` when you finish a line.

The fix is small:

```
            if((i>1 && i<n) && (j>1 && j<n)){ 
                printf("%d ",Board[x][y]);
                y++;
                if ((y%z) == 0)
                    x++;
            }
```

When you had `z` `y`s, it's time to go down one line (increment x).

The following code, which is your code with my modification prints the correct lines (I tried up to 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i,j;
    int y,x;
    int n,a,num,readNum,z;
    char ch;

    ch = 'a';
    num = 1;

    printf("Enter size\n");
    readNum = scanf("%d",&z);

    int Board[z][z];
    n = z+2;
    a = n+1;

    printf("Enter Array\n");
    for(x=0;x<z;x++){
        for(y=0;y<z;y++){
           readNum = scanf("%d",&Board[x][y]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nYour Array:\n");
    x=0;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        y=0;
        for(j=0;j<a;j++){
            if(((i==0)&&(j==1))||
               ((i==1)&&(j==0))||
               ((i==0)&&(j==n))||
               ((j==0)&&(i==n))){
                printf("   ");
            }
            if ((i==0)&&(j==0)){
                printf("  ");
            }
            if ((i==0 && (j>=2 && j<n))){
                printf("%c ",ch);
                ch++;
            }
            if ((j==0) &&(i>=2 && i<n)){
                printf("%d  ",num);
                num++;
            }
            if(((i==1) && (j>=1 && j<=n))||
               ((i==n) && (j>=1 && j<=n))||
               ((j==1) && (i>1  && i<n ))||
               ((j==n) && (i>1  && i<n ))){
                printf("# ");
            }
            if((i>1 && i<n) && (j>1 && j<n)){ 
                printf("%d ",Board[x][y]);
                y++;
                if ((y%z)==0)
                   x++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where exactly can i put x++ with it working out? because I tried but it just ruins the array by prints random numbers

Comment: just before `printf("\n");` at the end.

Comment: it just prints the last row in the first one in the frame and the rest of the rows are random numbers

Comment: Sorry for bad solution, see updated answer, I think you'd like that.

Comment: @Henry James the rest of the rows are random numbers  => have your tried to print out the actual content of your Board array?

Comment: @MByD I tried your solution it still gives me the random numbers.

Comment: @jv42 it gives me random numbers because x and y go beyond the size of the array

Comment: @Henry see updated answer. nothing new, just posted the whole code, and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
     printf("\nYour Array:\n");
     x=0;
```

you never change `x`.

Comment: i tried to increase x by every loop but it does not increase with respect to j so the array just prints out random numbers, you know where i can put it with it actually working?

Comment: insert the `x++` after the `printf("\n")`. You may need to initialize x with `-1` or `-2`: I didn't pay close attention to that specific issue.